# CSS Border Issue on Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, web, border, styling

I'm having trouble with different border colours and border-radius in css for my website.

I have created a box and added a border just to the top of the box as shown in the image below.

[image]

However, I wanted the top border to stretch the whole width of the box but the seems to be a problem. This problem only occurs with Google Chrome on pc, it seems fine on Safari and Internet Explorer.

```
#box {
    width:250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #acacac;
    position: absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:315px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top: 45px solid white;
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTMl + CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Seems like border-style is inset... Set it to solid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 border radius problem with Chrome, Opera, Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963696/css3-border-radius-problem-with-chrome-opera-safari)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with CSS borders and it's how you create the arrows that you see in some blogs. This is a limitation of how you can implement borders with rounded corners.